# iPhone application to make voice call

Tags: iphone, push, msisdn

I'm trying to make an iPhone application. In it, I want to add a module to make voice call using this application (msisdn is our input). Is this possible? If so, what is the result in iPod Touch?

Any body know how to notify push registry in iPhone? I can see in some site it is available in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

[Generate a call, sms, etc from iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988070/generate-a-call-sms-etc-from-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the Siphon project:
http://code.google.com/p/siphon/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to replace the dialer application, or simply invoke it? On official phones, the dialer cannot be replaced or have another application provide that functionality.

Comment: i am trying to invoke dialer application....? could we test in the iPhone simulator /

Comment: you can invoke, but cant test in simulator

Answer (score 0):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1234---"]];